# Change django template search path depending on request

Tags: django, templates

For my application I want to serve a different base.html (and other templates and static files) for visitors and for admins: visitors will see a customized themed frontend, admins will see the editor interface (not related to the django admin interface). Some templates / resources will be shared between the two frontends.

I know I can do this by having separate settings.py configurations and include different template paths in each of them through a django app, but that would also mean I have to run two instances of the app. I'd rather serve both frontends from a single instance (or pool of workers).

Is there a way to dynamically add extra folders to the Django search path? That should suit my needs: if the user comes through the visitor domain, search the added path first and then the defaults, else just use the default template search path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly why I've created [django_layers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django_layers)

It's inspired by the Plone skinning/layer system where you can switch skins and have the framework search different layers for templates, staticfiles, and so on. I was missing something similar in Django where, like you, the only option I could find was inheritance or distinct INSTALLED_APPS configurations.

It turns out it's also very suitable for other use-cases such as A/B testing.

The packages is relatively new, let me know if it works for you or if you have issues if you decide to use it.

Comment: It took some effort to wrap my head around this package, but it does the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) for this purpose, especially the `{% extends %}` template tag, which can accept variables instead of literal strings.

Example:

In your child templates make them extend unknown base template like this:

```
{% extends BASE_SITE_TEMPLATE %}

{% block page_head %}
    <!-- Custom per-page static files may be defined here -->
{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
    ...
{% endblock %}
```

And then write a template context processor that will pass the `BASE_SITE_TEMPLATE` variable based on your custom conditions to rendered templates:

```
def base_site_template(request):
    # Here goes your conditions to select proper base template, for example
    # by checking request.user permissions or some other logic.
    ...
    return {'BASE_SITE_TEMPLATE': ...}
```

Of course You will need to define various base templates, like `base_site_user.html`, `base_site_editor.html`, `base_site_admin.html`.

This method doesn't require you to change any of your views, just child templates, so I think it's one of the simplest methods to do what You want.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. I have considered an approach like this, but it requires me to be very explicit about how to inherit and include templates. It will also not work for third party apps that I include in my project.